# Can't update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`Register`)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am developing a full-stack React application. At the frontend, I have a user registration form. I am using React Query to post the form data to the `/api/users/register` endpoint. Once the data is POSTed successfully, I redirect the user to the home(`/`) route.

Everything is working as expected; however, I am getting this message in the console:

[image]

I don't know what is causing this warning.

I would appreciate any help.

The code samples are as follows:

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <Router>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <App />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </Router>
);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Login from "./components/Login";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Register.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const Register = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const mutation = useMutation((registerFormData) => {
    return axios.post("/api/users/register", registerFormData);
  });
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      name: Yup.string()
        .max(20, "Must be 20 characters or less")
        .required("Name is required."),
      email: Yup.string()
        .email("Invalid email address")
        .required("Email is required."),
      password: Yup.string()
        .min(5, "Must be 5 characters or more")
        .required("Password is required."),
    }),
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      mutation.mutate(values);
    },
  });

  mutation.isSuccess && navigate("/");

  return (
    <div className="register-form-container">
      <div>
        <h1>Register</h1>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          <input
            id="name"
            name="name"
            type="text"
            {...formik.getFieldProps("name")}
          />
          {formik.touched.name && formik.errors.name ? (
            <span>{formik.errors.name}</span>
          ) : null}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            id="email"
            name="email"
            type="email"
            {...formik.getFieldProps("email")}
          />
          {formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email ? (
            <span>{formik.errors.email}</span>
          ) : null}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            id="password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            {...formik.getFieldProps("password")}
          />
          {formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password ? (
            <span>{formik.errors.password}</span>
          ) : null}
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because you have a side effect on render phase of `Register` component.

Side effect

```
mutation.isSuccess && navigate("/");
```

You should handle your side effects in a `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (mutation.isSuccess) navigate("/")
}, [mutation, navigate]);
```

React makes sure to run effects after the component's render phase is finished.